# is there any way to pre-define a query in a model that runs whenever that model is called from context

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller

i have model in my mvc 5 project named operations.

```
public class Operation
    {
        public int OperationID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Commission { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
        public bool CommissionValidity { get; set; }
        public bool IsHidden { get; set; }
        public decimal Capacity { get; set; }
        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    }
```

requirement is whenever this model is called from context
like below

```
Var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
var Operations = db.Operations.tolist();
```

i want only the records to be loaded where IsHidden field is False without using where clause in query

is there any way like i make constructor or define getter Setter functions to acquire the goal.

Comment: if you generally want to list only to return `!hidden` elements you could create your own implementation of `toList()`, else create an extension method, either way at some point there is a where clause which filters the objects for your requirements

Comment: problem is there are numerous calls in the project to this model and now i have to filter all of them on the basis of Hidden status
thats why i am looking for a way to filter them at model stage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Entity Framework Core, you can use a [global query filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) to achieve this.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Operation>().HasFilter(o => !o.IsHidden);
}
```

---

Entity Framework 6 doesn't have query filters. For that, you'd need to use a different property on your `DbContext` to return your visible entities:

```
public IQueryable<Operation> VisibleOperations 
    => Set<Operation>().Where(o => !o.IsHidden);
```

However, you won't be able to use this filtered query to add or remove entities from the database, so you'll probably still need to expose the full `IDbSet<Operation>`, which won't have the filter applied.

Comment: i am using EntityFramework.6.2.0
ModelBuilder is not available in this